# kendo ui grid popup populating dropddown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a solution on how to get the selected data in a pop-up window using kendo ui grid. 
For example, I have a movie and want to change its genre. When I hit the edit button, the window opens up but the already assigned value is not displayed and I have to manually select it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: remoteDataSource,
        height: 500,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: "inline",
        columns: [{
          field: "Title",
          title: "Title"
        }, {
          field: "ReleaseDate",
          title: "Release Date",
          format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
        }, {
          field: "Price",
          title: "Price",
          format: "{0:c}",
          width: "130px"
        }, {
          field: "Genre.Title",
          title: "Genre",
          editor: genresDropDownEditor
        }, {
          field: "Rating.Title",
          title: "Rating",
          editor: ratingsDropDownEditor
        }, {
          command: ["edit", "destroy"]
        }]
      });
```

Below is the function that populates the dropdown list

```
function genresDropDownEditor(container, options) {
  console.log('genre options', options.model.Genre.Title, options);
  $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      autoBind: true,
      dataTextField: "Title",
      dataValueField: "Id",
      dataSource: {
        transport: {
          read: "http://localhost:62954/api/genres"
        }
      },
      value: options.model.Genre.Title
    });
}
```

[Before editing](http://prntscr.com/hxihd7)
[During editing](http://prntscr.com/hxihwt)

Thanks